# Как убрать отступы изображения?

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <img class="title" src="https://...">
</body>
```

Отдельно прописывая для класса title margin: 0px; не дает желаемого результата. Только так:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Проблема в том что сверху на фон должны ложиться еще несколько блоков с информацией и к ним будут применяться другие оступы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PPPP PPPP (@____) | Твиттер</title>
        <link type="icon-mask" href="http://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twitter.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img class="title" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/926069676/1421322841/1500x500">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

А так вовсе изображение не отображается:

```
<div class="title"></div>

.title {
  background: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/926069676/1421322841/1500x500);
}
```

Comment: Сперва попробуй сделать `.title { margin: -10px }`, может проблема в родительском элементе.

Comment: если убирание margin с класса применяемого к элементу не помогает, значит дело не в это элементе, и отступы могут быть у родительских, причем как margin так и padding, поэтому нужно рассматривать конкретный случай с конкретной разметкой

Comment: @MichaelPak, откуда число -10?

Comment: @Grundy, рандомное число для проверки.

Comment: @MichaelPak я не совсем понимаю, что здесь явл. родительским элементом для изображения. Код то пустой, только изображение и содержит. А с заданием отриц. значения отступов работает
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>PPPP PPPP (@____) | Твиттер</title>
      <link type="icon-mask" href="http://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twitter.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div><img class="title" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/926069676/1421322841/1500x500"></div>


  </body>

        </html>

Comment: @OlenaPotapenko, добавьте эту разметку в пост

Comment: @OlenaPotapenko, родительский - это элемент внутри которого находится изображение. начиная от элемента `<html>` и до `<div>` непосредственно внутри которого расположен тег `<img>`

Comment: @OlenaPotapenko, то есть ты хочешь поверх картинки добавить еще несколько элементов?

Comment: @MichaelPak - именно

Comment: @OlenaPotapenko, Тогда проще сделать ее фоном указав в стиле для дива `background: url("путь к картинке")`. Приведите пример что именно вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну второй вариант не работает потому-что не указана прямая ссылка на изображение. Прямая ссылка должна заканчиваться ее расширением типа img.jpg, а такие крутые площадки как твиттер скрывают их с помощью .htaccess или других крутых технологий, так что либо нужно найти фотохостинг с прямыми ссылками/арендовать сервер/пробовать на локалке.

Margin к картинке не работает вероятно потому что по умолчанию браузеры задают тегу body определенные отступы, например хром задает около 5-10px и что бы их убрать нужно прописывать обнуление отступов. Часто такие файлы называют reset.css и прописывают внутри что-то типа:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, address, acronym, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Многие браузеры применяют свои, обобщенные правила CSS, которые работают по умолчанию. Рекомендуется первой строчкой в файле css прописывать * {margin:0; padding:0}. И тогда вы уже все контролируете при дальнейшей разработке проекта. Стаья по теме - http://linux.yaroslavl.ru/docs/www/css/reset_css.html

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите контейнеру {font-size: 0px;}

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

чтобы убрать ВСЕ отступы, в стилях в начале пишу: `*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}` вроде работает